# Why doesn't DataReceived work on Mono?

Tags: events, mono, serial-port

I am wondering why DataRecevied (or ReadChar()) haven't been implemented in Mono. I couldn't find anything on the notes for the 3.x beta and both are old known issues ([The first is even mentioned on the Mono documentation](http://www.mono-project.com/HowToSystemIOPorts)) and seemingly easy to fix.
There are even "workarounds" such as [this](http://antanas.veiverys.com/enabling-serialport-datareceived-event-in-mono/) that feel not-so-hard to integrate.

Is there any solid reason for it being standing so long? Does nobody actually care? Is Mono not *really* under active development? The 3.x beta would point otherwise...

Comment: Getting asynchronous serial port I/O going on all the operating systems that Mono supports is not a lot of fun.  Mono is a FOSS project, things get done when there's a need.  They are no doubt waiting for your contribution.

Comment: I didn't want to come across as a judgmental ass and I am definitely impressed with what Mono delivers. I asked since there are, e.g. bugs filed to these issues with no response for a number of years and available workarounds -partial as they may be- by very smart people.I am sure there are reasons behind the state of things, I am just trying to understand better.

Answer (score 3):

Mono is under active development. Xamarin is the main company behind it (as in, number of contributions compared to other companies).

This means, of course, that bugs/features that the Mobile offerings use get prioritized faster than other things. Do you have a company that heavily uses the System.IO.Ports namespace? Then consider contributing to it, it hasn't received much love lately.

PS: You do not even need to code to start contributing. For example, first thing you could do is review contributions from others, like [this one](https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/616).

Comment: I don't have -professionally- a need for System.IO.Ports, but while using it as a hobby thing I've come across so many people describing ways to get around the issues (which have been around for so long) that it made me suspect the solution wasn't just a check-in away.

Comment: if everybody had the same approach as you, nobody would contribute to opensource projects (an open source project is never really "finished")

Comment: That's exactly why I am asking. I don't understand why nobody would e.g. answer to the bugs being filed in the system.
If most people had the same approach as me there would be a lot of questions, and hopefuly some answers, flying around. Are you a professional dev? You should know that getting into something like Mono and submitting code is a very delicate business. First I try to understand how things work, then I act.

Comment: Mono works in the same way as most open source projects out there: you find something that doesn't work, then either you file the bug and hope for someone to fix it, or contribute a patch and ask for review